# prove that 1\x has f distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

if $X$ has $F$ distribution with $v_1$ and $v_2$ degrees of freedom show that $ Y =\dfrac{1}{X}$ has an $F$ distribution with  $v_2$ and $v_1$ degrees of freedom

use this result to show that 
$$f_{1-\alpha,v_1,v_2}= \frac{1}{f_{\alpha,v_2,,v_1}}$$

Comment: Done. All of it. What now?

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. It can make it look as if you copied a question without understanding it, so no question is actually present in your own mind. That is probably why someone voted to close the question. People who vote to close for that reason should explain that here in the comments, but usually they don't.

Comment: @MichaelHardy "People who vote to close for that reason should explain that here in the comments" Your opinion, Michael, only your opinion. Reasons why the suggestion is nearly impractical, and certainly not an obligation, were explained to death on meta, *as you are well aware*.

Comment: @Did : I am well aware that a lot of words were written in threads where that was suggested. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Then you could try to somewhat reformulate your ritual admonestation "People who vote to close for that reason should explain that here in the comments, but usually they don't" to avoid naive readers being led to believe this is anything else than your pet opinion.

Comment: actually i have tried a lot with it but i used the function of f distribution and then transformation technique to transform from x to y but it was difficult to reach a result

Answer (score 2):

The F distibution with $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ degrees of freedom is usually defined to be the distribution of a quotient
$$
X = \frac{A/\nu_1}{B/\nu_2}
$$
where

- $A \sim \chi^2_{\nu_1}$, and
- $B \sim \chi^2_{\nu_2}$, and
- $A$ and $B$ are independent.

If that holds, then
$$
\frac 1 X = \frac{B/\nu_2}{A/\nu_1}.
$$
So apply the definition stated above.

Comment: for the second one how can i start shall i use integral or it can be proved by definition

Comment: @Ahb : For the second one just use the fact that $1/X$ is small if $X$ is big. $\qquad$